# jQuery: How to use .nextUntil()?

Tags: jquery, siblings

Suppose I have HTML like this:

```
<span class="buttonNo1">1</span>
<span class="buttonNo2">2</span>
<span class="buttonNo3 clicked">3</span>  //Suppose this button is clicked
<span class="buttonNo4">4</span>
<span class="buttonNo5">5</span>
<span class="buttonNo6">6</span>
<span class="buttonNo7">7</span>
```

Now, I want to get the `className` of next two adjacent siblings of the span which has the class `clicked` when `clicked` is clicked.

One simple method would be.

```
$(".clicked").click(function(e){
  console.log($(this).next().attr('class'))
  console.log($(this).next().next().attr('class'))
})
```

How to do it with `.nextUntil()`?

Comment: what is the expected output if `clicked` is clicked?

Comment: @ArunPJohny I want to change the `backgroundColour` and `innerHTML` of next two siblings when `clicked` is clicked!

Comment: of which two elements? buttonNo4 and buttonNo5

Comment: @ArunPJohny in this case, yeah.

Comment: Any reason why `.nextUntil()` needs to be used?

Comment: @Dom No, no reason as such. I thought using `.nextUntill()` will be the correct way to do it.

Comment: Personally, I feel chaining `.next()` would suffice.  I know it's a little ugly, but definitely gets the job done. However, @ArunPJohny provided a great answer!

Comment: @Dom chaining will be a problem because the OP wants a collection of two elements, in that case you need to use [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) also which will be messier

Comment: @ArunPJohny ah sorry, I overlooked the collection, thank you for clarifying that!

Comment: @Dom I have one mre doubt here. `$(this).siblings(':lt(2)').css('background-color', 'red');`. Why won't this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and [:lt()](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) filters

```
$(".clicked").click(function(e){
    $(this).nextAll(':lt(2)').css('background-color', 'red');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EPvq7/)

Comment: Could you please tell me what is `lt(2)` here ?

Comment: @NavneetSaini it's [`less than (lt)`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/). there is also a [`greater than (gt) selector`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have one mre doubt here. $(this).siblings(':lt(2)').css('background-color', 'red');. Why won't this work?

Comment: sibling will include previous and next elements